# Cakephp2.x(2.10.19) default max log files

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I'm using Cakephp.write(myfile, the content here)
The function works fine, log files is created in tmp/logs. But it just keeps 10 files .I want to keeps for more than 10 files, Please help...

Comment: Can you show us any code, configuration etc?

Comment: Hi, Mate00,
This is the config in bootstrap.php file
CakeLog::config('response', array(
 'engine' => 'File',
 'types' => array('response'),
 'file' => 'response',
));

And i'm using this line to write log:
CakeLog::write('request', {request data here})

Answer (score 0):

Per [the manual](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/logging.html#creating-and-configuring-log-streams), you need to add `'rotate' => x` to your log configuration, where `x` is the number of logs to keep. 10 is the default.

Comment: Hi Greg,
i have tried to add the value like this, but still not works:
CakeLog::config('dev', array(
 'engine' => 'File',
 'types' => array('dev'),
 'file' => 'dev',
 'rotate' => 20
));

Comment: That sure looks like it should work. I'd suggest doing some debugging of the logger itself to see why that's not having the expected effect.